# Stop automatic stats gathering on a specific table

Tags: database, oracle

I know how to stop automatic stats gathering for the whole database, but how would I stop it for a specific table only?

I have searched for this information a lot but there only seems to be information for stopping it for an entire database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `DBMS_STATS.LOCK_TABLE_STATS` for the table.